# Maintain splitter window's proportions during resizing

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a main window derived from `CFrameWnd` that contains vertical and horizontal `CSplitterWnd`.
I would like to maintain their pane proportions during resizing.
Both vertical and horizontal splitter have 2 panes, so main window looks like a Cartesian coordinate system.

I have tried the following in the `OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)` handler:

```
void CMainFrame::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CFrameWnd::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    int iCX = 0, iCY = 0, iCX2 = 0, iCY2 = 0,
        iCYMin = 0, iCXMin = 0;     // dummy variables, required by the API, not used

    m_wndSplitter.GetRowInfo(0, iCY, iCYMin);
    m_wndSplitter.GetRowInfo(1, iCY2, iCYMin);

    m_wndSplitter2.GetColumnInfo(0, iCX, iCXMin);
    m_wndSplitter2.GetColumnInfo(1, iCX2, iCXMin);

    double row_scaling_coefficient = static_cast<double>(iCY) / static_cast<double>(iCY2 + iCY);
    double column_scaling_coefficient = static_cast<double>(iCX) / static_cast<double>(iCX + iCX2);

    iCX = static_cast<int>(column_scaling_coefficient * static_cast<double>(cy) + 0.5);
    iCY = static_cast<int>(row_scaling_coefficient * static_cast<double>(cx)+ 0.5);

    //================ dirty workaround, since RecalcLayout() does not work if size remains unchanged 
    // we +1 so CSplitterWnd registers size change
    m_wndSplitter.SetRowInfo(0, iCY + 1, 0);
    m_wndSplitter2.SetColumnInfo(0, iCX + 1, 0);

    m_wndSplitter.RecalcLayout();
    m_wndSplitter2.RecalcLayout();

    // then reset to actual size
    m_wndSplitter.SetRowInfo(0, iCY, 0);
    m_wndSplitter2.SetColumnInfo(0, iCX, 0);

    m_wndSplitter.RecalcLayout();
    m_wndSplitter2.RecalcLayout();
    //======================================
}
```

The above code does not produce desired result, so I have decided to ask here for help while I Google and try to figure it out on my own.
If you have any questions leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would override  [`virtual void RecalcLayout();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/csplitterwnd-class?view=msvc-160#recalclayout) in your `m_wndSplitter` class and adjust panel sizes per your requirements there.

You may have to derive your own class from `CSplitterWnd` if you haven't done that already.